How to display the bluetooth devices near a raspberry pi for a limited amount of time?
I would like that the following script runs for a certain time (let's say 10 sec) e lists the available bluetooth devices near a RaspBerry Pi 4.
When I run the following script (adapted from this question) no results out of the interfaces_added callback are displayed. What I am doing wrong here, please?
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus, dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
from gi.repository import GLib

import sys, signal, time
import bluezutils

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = "org.bluez"
BLUEZ_NAMESPACE = "/org/bluez/"
DBUS_OM_PROPERTIES="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'

ADAPTER_INTERFACE = BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME + ".Adapter1"
DEVICE_INTERFACE = BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME + ".Device1"

TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000
            
class GetNewDevices(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, '/org/freedesktop/DBus')
        self.setup_timeout(TIMEOUT)
        self.listen_for_signal(bus)

    def setup_timeout(self, timeout):
        GLib.timeout_add(timeout, self.handler)

    def listen_for_signal(self, bus):
        bus.add_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_added, bus_name=BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME,
        dbus_interface=DBUS_OM_IFACE,
        signal_name="InterfacesAdded",
        )

    def handler(self):
        # This handler is used for both timeout and signal
        self.loop.quit()

    def interfaces_added(self, *args): #path, interfaces):
        print(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    adapter = bluezutils.find_adapter()
    adapter.StartDiscovery()

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    a = GetNewDevices(loop)
    loop.run()
    print("Exited mainloop, continuing program...")


I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, but my guess is that you need to do the StartDiscovery() call after creating your GetNewDevices object.  If the devices were already known to the Bluetooth stack, they might have been delivered immediately after starting discovery - and were lost because you hadn't set up your handler for them yet.

I found the answer looking again at the [Bluez API documentation][1]
[1]: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-gatt-profile and managed to correctly create the service object. Here is the complete working code:
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus, dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
from gi.repository import GLib

import sys, signal, time
import bluezutils

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = "org.bluez"
BLUEZ_NAMESPACE = "/org/bluez/"
DBUS_OM_PROPERTIES="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'

ADAPTER_INTERFACE = BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME + ".Adapter1"
DEVICE_INTERFACE = BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME + ".Device1"

TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000
            
class Application(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, mainloop):
        self.mainloop = mainloop
        self.path = '/'
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
        self.setup_timeout(TIMEOUT)
        self.listen_for_signal(bus)

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def setup_timeout(self, timeout):
        GLib.timeout_add(timeout, self.handler)

    def listen_for_signal(self, bus):
        bus.add_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_added, bus_name=BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME,
        dbus_interface=DBUS_OM_IFACE,
        signal_name="InterfacesAdded",
        )

    def handler(self):
        self.mainloop.quit()

    def interfaces_added(self, *args): #path, interfaces):
        print(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    path = bluezutils.find_adapter().object_path

    adapter = bluezutils.find_adapter()
    adapter.StartDiscovery()

    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
    app = Application(mainloop)
    mainloop.run()
    print("Exited mainloop, continuing program...")

